# how to perform VLOOKUP on two separate excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have two separate excel files.
I want to

**copy** the value of column `code` from file 1

**and paste it to** a new column (lets say `code`) in file 2

**where** the value of column `ID` of file 1 is equal to that of file 2.

file 1:

| blah | ID | code | blah blah blah |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 10100000200 | 527411 |  |
|  | 10104352345 | 527421 |  |
|  | 12345234200 | 527441 |  |
|  | 74564536345 | 524567 |  |

file 2:

| ID | code |
| --- | --- |
| 10100000200 |  |

***here is what I tried so far:***

I select the `code` column in file 2 and in function field I type this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2, '[file1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$C$4545, 2, FALSE)
```

But I get `#N/A` error.
What is my mistake?

---

**update**

I select cell `W2` of file2, then I write the above formula for it. I want `vlookup` to search for the value of `C2` cell in file1 (which is in `B` column) and copy the value of column `C` into `W2` of file2.

Comment: Which version of Excel? Have you tried entering your formula as an array formula? (press CTL, SHIFT and ENTER keys rather than just the ENTER key when typing formula into a cell) Which worksheet columns correspond to your "ID" and "code" columns in file 2? `#N/A` generally indicates the value being looked cannot be found in the first column of the looked up  range.

Comment: Ok, so you have now changed your formula (but did not mention this). Which cell in file 2 has the ID value of  `10100000200`? It should be in cell `C2` if your formula is to work. And both workbooks (files) will need to be open.

Comment: @DMM yes both files are open and the ID column is in `C` column which starts from second row.

Comment: @DMM I changed the format of cells to numbers but the error stays on!

Comment: Probably a data error. Try some basic problem solving. See if you can make `VLOOKUP()` work on the same worksheet, then same workbook, then two workbooks. Use functions like `ISNUMBER` to check you are comparing like with like, use simplified ID values to avoid errors like comparing different numbers.

Comment: @DMM it's unbelievable! I double-clicked on `C2` cell and `VLOOKUP` worked!!!! without any other change!!!! it's like excel got to understand the content of `C2` by that double-click! Thank you!

Comment: Is the file 2 ID column in column C?

Comment: @Lee yes. The problem is solved. previous comment